# Android: How to make Swipe to the right screen and open a new activity 2

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

**I can not add the swipe right, I want to open a new activity after swipe right**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements   View.OnTouchListener{

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       /* Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
*/
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


     /* FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
      fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                      .setAction("Action", null).show();
          }
      });*/

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);

        startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }

  /**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:

                    return "SECTION 1";
                case 1:
                    return "SECTION 2";
                case 2:
                    return "SECTION 3";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";


        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
           // TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            //textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a page change listener to your ViewPager and launch the new activity when detect the swipe right:

```
//Global variable 
int previousPosition = 0;
.
.
.
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
            if(previousPosition < position){
              Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
             }
             previousPosition = position;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone has this problem in 2019, there is a nice method I found on youtube. I implemented the code on an empty activity in my project.

```
public class RSA extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
public static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
public static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rsa);
    this.setTitle("RSA"); // edit the action bar text
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent downEvent, MotionEvent moveEvent, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    boolean result = false;
    float diffY = moveEvent.getY() - downEvent.getY();
    float diffX = moveEvent.getX() - downEvent.getX();
    //which movement was greater, across x or y
    if(Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)){
        //swipe left or right
        if(Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD){
            if(diffX > 0){
                //swipe right

            } else {
                //swipe left
            }
            result = true;
        }
    } else {
        //up or down swipe
        if(Math.abs(diffY)> SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(diffY)> SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD){
            if(diffY > 0){
                //bottom swipe
                onSwipeBottom();
            } else {
                //topswipe
                onSwipeTop();
            }
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private void onSwipeBottom() {
    //here we start the bottom activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, rsaAlgorithm.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void onSwipeTop() {
    //here we start the info activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, rsaInformation.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

}

A lot of parts in the code are self explanatory, but if you have questions feel free to ask.
You will need to import a few things, just alt+enter on the red text that appears. 
The youtube video that helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32rSs4tE-mc&list=LLgb_VsN-nX-URXVVHvn4b4g&index=4&t=0s

It is important to alt+enter on GestureDetector.OnGestureListener when you implement it in the class in order to add the needed methods by default.

I implemented swipe top and bottom, and if you want to complete swipe right, just add the code from the onSwipebottom/top method into the onSwipeRight method. The intent will open your new activity. You will need to edit it to work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a listener to your `ViewPager` . Add this line to your code

```
mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(this);
```